# How to hide an iframe div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Iam trying to hide a div element inside an iframe using `.contents()` method and then get the required element from the given iframe and hide it, but it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myframe').contents().find('#logo-events').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://api.jquery.com/contents"  border="0" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" width="100%"  style="min-height:600px"></iframe>
```

Comment: use frame load instead of document load.

Answer (score 2):

**Look at your JavaScript error console**!

> Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "`http://api.jquery.com`" from accessing a frame at "`null`".  Both frames are sandboxed and lack the "`allow-same-origin`" flag.

The contents of the iframe are on a different origin to the page you are running the JavaScript on. The same origin policy prevents your code from accessing the data. (Imagine if it was someone's online banking website and you should be able to see why).

If you had control over the other website (since you (probably) don't work for jQuery, you do not) then you could use `postMessage` to trigger an event handler provided by that site which would do the hiding.

Comment: but what if in my real case the iframe page and the page calling this iframe, belong to the same content(two php files in the same website)?